# clustering with a maximum inner distance threshold in Matlab

Tags: clustering

I'd like to get clusters with a maximum inner distance threshold between data points and center of cluster in Matlab programming.
Consider that I have a set of data points. I am going to divide them into different clusters using clustering algorithm such as k mean. My goal is to make this clustering in a way that max distance from each data points to their corresponding center be lower than threshold value. This threshold should be selected by user.
Is there any way to coding this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Implement *Leader* clustering yourself.

I'm fairly certain you *can* do this in Matlab.